# How to set multiple if/elseif conditions with multiple execute parameters

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code which is an assignment given to us and is really giving me a hard time, what i want to achieve is simple, if the user inputs either an already taken email or date then the program will not continue and will echo an error. But my he also wants us to output "Date is already taken!" if the date the user trying to insert is already in the database and "Email is already taken!" if the email is taken and "Sorry, Email and date are both taken!"..

What I'm trying to say is like this:

-INPUT # 1-

Enter Date: Example Date // Assuming date is already taken.

Enter Email: john@example.com

-OUTPUT # 1-

Sorry! Date is already taken!

-INPUT # 2-

Enter Date: Example Date

Enter Email: john@example.com // Assuming email is already taken.

-OUTPUT # 2-
Sorry! Email is already taken!

-INPUT # 3-

Enter Date: Example Date // Assuming date is already taken.

Enter Email: john@example.com // Assuming email is also taken.

-OUTPUT # 3-

Sorry, Email and date are both taken!

```
$emailadd = $_POST['eadd'];
$rdate = $_POST['date'];

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tblclient.ClientID,
                                   tblreservation.ReservationID,
                                   tblclient.EmailAdd,
                                   tblreservation.Date
                            FROM   tblclient
                            INNER JOIN tblreservation
                            ON     tblclient.ClientID = tblreservation.ReservationID
                            WHERE EmailAdd = ?
                            OR    Date = ? ");
    $result = $stmt->execute([$emailadd, $rdate]);
    if ($stmt->execute([$emailadd, $rdate]) > 0 ) {
        echo "Email already exist!";
    }
        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tblclient(
                    Fname,
                    Lname,
                    MI,
                    Address,
                    ContactNo,
                    EmailAdd)
            VALUES (
                    '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['fname'])) . "',
                    '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['lname'])) . "',
                    '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['mname'])) . "',
                    '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['add'])) . "',
                    '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['telno'])) . "',
                    '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['eadd'])) . "')";
            $conn->exec($sql);
                try {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblreservation(
                        ReservationPrice,
                        ReservationDate,
                        ReservationTime,
                        ReservationStatus)
                VALUES (
                        '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['price'])) . "',
                        '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['date'])) . "',
                        '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['time'])) . "',
                        '" . urldecode(trim($_POST['status'])) . "')";
                $conn->exec($sql);                  
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e;
                }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

I also tried using

```
if ($stmt->execute([$emailadd]) > 0 ) {
            echo "Email already exist!";
        } elseif ($stmt->execute([$rdate]) > 0 ) {
            echo "Date already exist!";
        }
```

Also no luck :( any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest this way

```
$ERROR = 0;
$ARR_ERROR = array();


if ($stmt->execute([$emailadd]) > 0 ) {
    $ERROR = 1;
    $ARR_ERROR['error'][] = "Email already exist!";
} 

if ($stmt->execute([$rdate]) > 0 ) {
    $ERROR = 1;
    $ARR_ERROR['error'][] = "Date already exist!";
}

// You can add more if statement here



// Show errors if there is

if($ERROR == 1){
    foreach($ARR_ERROR['error'] as $singleError){
        echo $singleError;
    }
}
```

In this way you will be able to show multiple errors.